# Search in GI Gives error while using Sector field

Tags: acumatica

I have created a Name value pair field for Sales Order table and Search is giving error while using the field from Description field in selector

```
#region UsrLoader

    public abstract class usrLoader : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(128, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Operator 1")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
            new Type[]
            {
             typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
             typeof(EPEmployee.acctName)
            },
              DescriptionField = typeof(EPEmployee.acctName))]
    public virtual string UsrLoader { get; set; }


    #endregion
    #region UsrUnLoader


    [PXDBString(128)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Operator 2")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
            new Type[]
            {
             typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
             typeof(EPEmployee.acctName)
            },
              DescriptionField = typeof(EPEmployee.acctName))]
    public virtual string UsrUnLoader { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrUnLoader : IBqlField { }

    #endregion
```

[image]

I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: What is the build number of your Acumatica instance?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I see the Invalid column error when the customization hasn't been published to insert the field in the database table. Did you publish after adding the fields?

Also, the warnings might tell you to join in the parent table. Did you try doing a join to the EPEmployee table to use the description/name field in your GI?

Comment: Yes. The fields are used in custom screens and it saves the data without any issue. The issue is with descriptor field used in GI.

Using custom field in the GI is not giving any error.

Comment: Did you try to include the EPEmployee table into your GI?